# Circe-Optics how to specify a path with dash

Tags: scala, circe-optics

I am trying to access a field in json with circe-optics. Issue is the field contains a dash:

`root.TAB-NR.string`

While if i write

`root.TAB_NR.string` it works, but the field does not exist.

Any idea how i can handle this case ?

Comment: Did you try with backticks ``root.`TAB-NR`.string``?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to use special characters in Scala identifiers that would otherwise be illegal, you can use backticks to quote them.

```
val `my funky value` = root.`TAB-NR`.string
```